# Where to find 'Identify feature' tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

It used to be an arrow with `i`. Now I have different version, I have gone through all the buttons and panels but cannot find it!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to View>Toolbars and make sure that the Attributes toolbar is active.

[image]

Once you turn on this toolbar the Identify button will become available after the toolbar appears.

Comment: thanks, perfect! Is it possible to reduce the number of icons that appear in this toolbar?

Comment: To turn off items on the toolbar go to Settings>Customization.  On the Customization dialog, expand the Toolbars list, and then expand the mAttributes toolbar list.  Uncheck any tools you do not need, and then restart the application.  When you re-open the application any tools you unchecked will no longer show on the toolbar.

Comment: thanks. Bit dissappointed by the clumsiness (cannot do it directly, needs restart etc.) and the fact that the tree is inconsistent - some actions have name and icon, some don't...

Answer (score 2):

"Identify Features", part of the toolbar "Attributes". Right click in the toolbar and check "attributes", then some more icons appear, among them "Identify Features".

Answer (score 1):

View - Identify features

or

View - Toolbars - Attribute toolbar

[image]